# How to export a variable which has reserved name in ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

As we know, this a syntax of ES6 of exporting a variable.

`export const LANGUAGE = 'JavaScript'`

and this is a way of declaration of the same code in ES5:

`exports.LANGUAGE = 'JavaScript'`

but in some other cases it doesn't work, like for reserved words and for names which includes spaces:

`exports.true = '#true'
exports['some text'] = 'text'`

so what is the right way of declaring exports in ES6 ?

Comment: [ES6 15.2.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports) `ExportSpecifier :IdentifierName; IdentifierName as IdentifierName` [ES6 15.2.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports-static-semantics-early-errors) *"...For each IdentifierName n in ReferencedBindings of ExportClause : It is a Syntax Error if StringValue of n is a ReservedWord..."* So looks like you can't, which shouldn't be much of a surprise. Is there a reason you need this? Could you just export an object instead, since object properties *can* use reserved words?

Comment: Seemed odd that `15.2.3` allowed reserved words, but then `15.2.3.1` disallowed them. The reason for this seems to be in the explanation of "Static Semantic Rules" [ES6 5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantic-rules). So the grammar itself permits it but then the semantics "enhance" the meaning of the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `export const varName = 'Value'` syntax with a reserved word; please read the following statement on [ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#exporting):

> Note that you can’t use reserved words (such as default and new) as variable names, but you can use them as names for exports (you can also use them as property names in ECMAScript 5). If you want to directly import such named exports, you have to rename them to proper variables names.

According to that, it looks like you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
const true_ = '#true';

export { true_ as true };
```

Please note that this will also cause problems on the importing side as well. You will most likely need to re-alias on import. E.g.,

```
import { true as true_ } from '...';
```

Comment: Is that quote dated or is my reading of the spec linked above inaccurate. I see that they first allow names that include reserved words but then in the next section seem to count it as an error. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the `15.2.3.1 Static Semantics: Early Errors` section means.

Comment: nm, I think the comment I added above answers it.